# Long-range RF comm with decent data rate

Tags: arduino, rf, video-transmitter, quad-copter

I'm building a quadcopter powered with Arduino. For testing purposes, I'm currently using bluetooth. In the future, however, I would like to have some form of fairly long range communication that also has a respectable data rate. The reason is that eventually I'd like to attach a [µCAM](http://www.4dsystems.com.au/downloads/micro-CAM/Docs/uCAM-DS-rev4.pdf) to the copter for FPV (probably will end up being low-bit grayscale). I have looked at the Synapse SM700, but it appears to be discontinued, and complicated to use with Arduino. I'm using an Arduino Pro Mini. Another option I'm considering is taking a transmitter-receiver pair from a regular quadcopter controller- something similar to [this](http://hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__14349__FrSky_DJT_2_4Ghz_Combo_Pack_for_JR_w_Telemetry_Module_V8FR_II_RX.html). Would I be able to send video over it? It seems I'd need to do something to convert digital signals from the camera to aux signals. Would it be possible? Transmitter  (receiver can be fairly large as well). In short, I'm looking for an RF system with 1-2 km. of range which I can use to send low-quality grayscale video and control signals to the quadcopter. Transmitter can be any size, and receiver can be fairly large/heavy. Is there anything on the market like this, or am I out of luck?

Comment: There are any number of WiFi transceiver modules available. 
Cheap and probably suitable are the many NRF24L01 modules with a suitable antenna. Here is a good example of a DIY system   https://achuwilson.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/long-range-rf-link-using-nrf24l01-rf-transceiver/ ...

Comment: ... with the antenna design being the "enabling technology". This is essentially a bent piece of Copper wire (albeit bent in a rather special way) plus an Al sheet groundplane.  He reports ~= 2 km line of side which is presumably ground-ground. Ground-air should be substantially greater. At 2kn your copter would be invisible and you'd be an order of magnitude or so being what most licence arrangements would allow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are any number of WiFi or 2.4 GHz ISM band no-licence-needed transceiver modules available.
Cheap and probably suitable are the many NRF24L01 modules with a suitable antenna.

Here is a good example of a DIY system. This is actually SPI - SPI requiring some work on your part for interfacing.
https://achuwilson.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/long-range-rf-link-using-nrf24l01-rf-transceiver/

Typical 2.4 GHz ISM band NRF24L01 module - this one with external antenna. Often under $10 each. Or two for $5 from China. (The external antenna connector is a significant contributor to the cost :-) ).

[image]

Here the antenna design is the "enabling technology".
This is essentially a bent piece of Copper wire (albeit bent in a rather special way) plus an Al sheet groundplane.

He reports ~= 2 km line of side which is presumably ground-ground. Ground-air should be substantially greater. At 2km your copter would be invisible and you'd be an order of magnitude or so being what most licence arrangements would allow.

---

There are even cheaper units that provide either UART interfaces with ease or full WiFi interfaces with due digging through the enthusiast literature. eg ESP8266 IC based modules cost typically about $US5 to $10 retail (SEED studio et al) and can be used as a UART bridge but contain an accessible embedded microcontroller with 802.11 stack.

Example - this one with on board antenna. Ranges of 2+ km ground-ground are reported using a "rubber ducky" 1/4 wave loaded aerial at portable/mobile end.

[image]
cropped.jpg

Comment: I'll look into the NRF24L01+, and see how it goes. Thanks for the answer!